# User Must Have Selection for input or dropdown

Tags: jquery, niceforms

The idea here is that the user can only have one selection for an input text box with an id of itemURL or have a selection made for the contentPageID. If the user starts typing a response into the itemURL it makes the contentPageID dropdown back to 0 for the value which is the - Select - for the text option. If the user then changes their mind and starts to make a selection with the dropdown then it clears out the value of the itemURL text field. I've used the following code however I'm using niceforms and it has to be maniupulated a little more and not sure how.

```
$('contentPageID, itemURL').change ( function () { 
if ( $(this).is ('select') ) {
    $('itemURL').val ("");
}
else {
    $('contentPageID').val (0);
}
} );
```

I do have a reset function that uses this to clear a dropdown but not sure how to work it into what I want to do.

```
$('select').each(function(){
                        var option = $('option:selected', this).html();
                        var niceselect = $(this).parents('dd').find('.NFSelectRight');
                        niceselect.html(option);
                        $(this).parents('dd')
                        .find('.NFSelectTarget a')
                        .removeClass('NFOptionActive')
                        .filter(':first').addClass('NFOptionActive');
                    });
```

Comment: jsfiddle for a start is usually good idea ;)

Comment: in general - niceforms are very invasive and with the amount of non-standard tasks you want to acomplish with your forms, you would have to handle niceforms additionally each time, so your application will be hard to maintain and potentially buggy

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this though because with the rest of my cms it really flows well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm using niceforms and it has to be maniupulated a little more and not sure how.*

my earlier code:

```
function updateNiceformSelect() {

    $('select.NFhidden').each(function(){
        var option = $('option:selected', this).html();
        var niceselect = $(this).parents('dd').find('.NFSelectRight');
        niceselect.html(option);

        $(this).parents('dd')
            .find('.NFSelectTarget a')
            .removeClass('NFOptionActive')
            .each(function(){
                if($(this).html() == option)
                    $(this).addClass('NFOptionActive');
            });
    });
};
```

It updates niceforms select to the value of underlying html select.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/EwpXp/14/

Niceform uses native inputs so they do not need to be handled separately

/edit

whole working code: http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/YvGDH/5/

It was harder that I thought

Comment: I understand that but how to do I do it to where if a user starts typing in the itemURL text box then it updates the dropdown to the default - Select - and if a user goes to make a selection in the dropdown then it clears out the text box.

Comment: You have posted code for usual forms. After that - update niceforms with my snippet

Comment: You are missing one of my fields. The itemURL text field which is important.

Comment: itemURL is an input so niceforms are not duplicating it

Comment: I'm looking at your fiddle and there's no itemURL text box.

Comment: The point of my question is the user can only have a selection for the itemURL or contentPageID dropdown. So you'd have to have the itemURL text box.

Comment: In your question - there is a piece of code handling itemURL. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Jacek_FH let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2195/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-jacek-fh)